# If you 'discount' me, you are 9! Is that okay?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-usage

Discount as a verb is clear to me. I just spoke this sentence without thinking. But now I think I goofed up. However, it tickled a question in my brain.

What's the opposite to the verb *count?* - Uncount is not found anywhere, discount is the word but with different meaning.

Consider our group has arranged for a picnic. But I'm pretty not sure about it. And I say...

> "Okay, let's count first..... fine... we are ten in total. And you guys should arrange for the accommodation and food accordingly. But mind it, I may have some undeniable work on that day. And thus, if you ***discount*** me, you are nine.

Dictionaries' definitions for the [verb *discount*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/discount_2) does not support my sentence. And, I don't want to use *...if you don't count me...*. Furthermore, *[uncount](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/uncount-noun)* won't work that way (it's really funny - OALD redirects *uncount* to the entry of *uncountable noun!*) :P

---

Thanks to the answerers. *Exclude* fits better but then I asked in **contrast** to the word *count*.

> If you ***include*** me, we are ten but if you ***exclude*** me, you are nine - is **fine**.

But, my concern is...

> If you ***count*** me, we are ten but if you ***discount/uncount*** me, you are nine.

Comment: good question -- but the truth is, I think the answer you don't want ("don't count") is the only answer there is. (You could say, "excluding me" instead of "if you don't count me" to get the point across.) Since I might be wrong, I am leaving this as a comment and not a response.

Comment: "Exclude" would be better here (to mean: not including in a group), although "discount" would probably be understood correctly in this example.

Comment: In contrast to *let's count...* I want to use *uncount/discount* that's it! You know *matching-matching* lol

Comment: You've just invented a word. Without people like you and Shakespeare, we'd be all the poorer!

Comment: @user42307 lol. Thanks but I'm just a poor learner still struggling with *if not...* clause use. haha

Comment: Well, to be honest I do get the impression that people are starting to use the word "dis-count" clumsily so as to ignore someone or something in the counting, (as scientists do when they reject some test data) but you're doing your bit to popularise the usage.

Comment: If you want to be really brief, I think you could use, "Without me, ..."

Comment: It's completely acceptable to say, "If you count me ... , but if you exclude me ... ."

Comment: I think you might be looking for a distinction like _count me in_ (include me) versus _count me out_ (exclude me).

Comment: @oerkelens WOW :P This is completely out of the world Great buddy. +1

Comment: FWIW I'm completely untroubled by "if you discount me", to me it conveys what you want and is not over-formal. Cambridge dictionary lists the meaning "to decide that something or someone is not worth considering or giving attention" for British English but *not* for American English, so I suppose that accounts for the general incredulity above. But I don't like "undeniable work": (1) it's not the work that would be denied if you could, it's the request to do the work, (2) in any case "undeniable" is commonly used for a fact that can't be denied, not a request. Use "unavoidable work".

Comment: ... the only possible thing against it, I suppose, is that because you've just talked about counting, "discount" could *maybe* be seen as an attempt at a pun. At which it fails, since by etymology "discount" did literally mean "dis-count", that is to say it does relate to counting and both current meanings are derived from that.

Comment: Not every action has an antonym in the sense that you're asking for. The problem is that "count" is something you actively do, and "not count" is something you accomplish by not doing something. What is the opposite of carry? "If you carry this package, you will being holding too much weight. If you don't carry it, you will be fine."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll be referring to [the definitions of *count* from Oxford Learner's](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/count_1) in my answer.

*Don't count* is the closest to an opposite for *count* in the sense of numbering in sequence (definition 1). There's no pure antonym here; what could be the opposite of saying "1, 2, 3..."? [Some thesauruses](http://thesaurus.com/browse/count) list words like *guess* as antonyms for this case, but I strongly disagree with that.

Definition 2 means *calculating a total by summing up the number of members*. This is the sense used in your example (*let's count... ten in total*). As with definition 1, there's no true antonym, for the same reasons. Similarly, you can get the right essential meaning with *don't count*, and it would be correct to use in your example:

> And thus, if you *don't count* me, you are nine.

But we can get better results with definition 3, *include*. *Exclude* is its appropriate antonym. It's also correct to say it in place of *discount* in your example:

> And thus, if you *exclude* me, you are nine.

Using *exclude* causes a definitional shift in the usage of *count* (changing from 2 to 3), which technically changes the meaning. Outside of situations where semantic pedantry is part and parcel (e.g. the law, professional philosophy, ridiculously close linguistic analysis, internet arguments), nobody will care about this. Everyone (discounting those who don't know enough English) will grasp the meaning without any problems.

Since you've discounted *don't count*, *exclude* is the best choice.

Definitions 4, 5 and 6 all have the same antonym: *discount*. See [definition 1 from OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/discount_2), which I actually find rather lacking; *discount* can also mean *ignore*, *not include*, *minimize*, etc. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discount) is more complete here.

*Discount* is in your example. While semantically (and grammatically) correct, *discount* is too formal for the context, making the response sound strange. For a group of people organizing a trip together the phrasing just sounds weird, though the meaning is clear. Using *discount* makes *count* definitionally shift, as *exclude* does. However, here the "distance" between the definitions is noticeably greater and makes the change awkward; in general conversation, people *will* stumble over this. *Exclude* is a better choice.

> OALD redirects *uncount* to the entry of *uncountable noun*!

That's because it's a standard abbreviation for *uncountable [noun]* in dictionaries. But as you've found out, it's not a word in and of itself.

---

You've clarified that you're after *[le mot juste](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mot%20juste)* to complement *count*. I agree that *count/exclude* and *count/don't count* aren't as eloquent as a cognate pair, such as *include/exclude*. However, I'm afraid my vocabulary's at an end here; I don't know of a single-word, etymologically related antonym for this sense of *count*.

For a simple drop-in replacement, I recommend *exclude* or *don't count*. I realize that's not what you're after, but in terms of an easy, quick and accurate solution this is the best way to go. Additional apropos alternatives:

- Use *include / exclude* instead of *count / antonym-of-count*.
- Restructure the passage to use *with / without me* or something along those lines, [as suggested by Damkerng T](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27798/if-you-discount-me-you-are-9-is-that-okay/27801#comment52382_27798).

If your heart is dead set on some sort of *count* pairing, you could use *discount*, but I think it's self defeating to use an awkward, contrived sounding phrasing for the sake of preserving a nice juxtaposition of vocabulary. If you're going to do so, I suggest using *counting/discounting* and upping the formality for the sake of making things marginally less peculiar. Something along these lines, for example:

> OK, we are ten, counting everyone, but mind that I might have some unavoidable work that day. Discounting me and planning for a group of nine might be wise. Please arrange for the food and accommodation accordingly.

Bear in mind that while these sentences are now consistent and don't mix registers, they are still too formal for the context. Someone planning a vacation with friends and who's been using phrases like *you guys* should expect to receive some quizzical looks if they start talking in this fashion.

Comment: I certainly know the word *exclude* and the phrase *don't count*. However, the former word fits better in contrast to *include*. If you *include* me, we are ten and if you *exclude* me, you are nine is **fine**. But if you *count* me, we are ten and you *exclude* me, you are nine. That's why I said in **contrast** to *count* - uncount/discount! :)

Comment: I've made a substantial edit and addition to address your update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of the word "count" in a context like this is "don't count". There is no single word. To express the idea you are describing, you would say, "If you don't count me, then there are only 9 in the group."

By the way, we wouldn't normally say "you are only nine", but rather "there are only nine". "You are only nine" is not wrong, fluent speakers say it sometimes, but not often.

Note that there are many verbs that don't have an opposite. I haven't done a review, but I'd guess that most verbs do not. Like we have a verb "eat", but there's no single word meaning "not eat". We have a verb look, but no single verb meaning "don't look". We don't say "uneat" or "dislook", etc. If you want to express the idea that someone DIDN'T do X, normally you just say "didn't do X", in most cases there's no special word for it.